# Could it be that there's a bug in the Windows Restart Manager callback API?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, calling-convention, restartmanager

As I was investigating a weird crash that I could only reproduce on Windows 8, I found that the `EBX` register was not restored from calls to either [`RmShutdown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373667%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [`RmRestart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373665%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The first difference I found with running on Windows 8, is that it's using `ECX` while the win7 version of these functions use (and thus restore) `EBX`. (I have not investigated other Windows versions closely, just noticed that the bug doesn't repro on Vista.)

When I dug further, I noticed that the call to the [`RM_WRITE_STATUS_CALLBACK`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373678%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) doesn't restore the stack by popping the arguments from it as it seems to be expected by the caller which doesn't do it either. So when `RstrtMgr!CRestartManager::ShutdownApplications` calls `RstrtMgr!_EH_epilog3` the wrong register values are popped from the stack. But at least, `ESP` is restored properly and the end of `RmShutdown` properly reset the registers it used, including `EBP`, which it doesn't use between the call to `CRestartManager::ShutdownApplications` and the end...

So on Windows 7, all was fine... But the Windows 8 version, since `ECX` is used instead of `EBX`, `EBX` is not restored and if the calling code depends on it... BOOM!!!

To fix this, I simply changed the callback function to use `__stdcall` (this means I couldn't use the real `RM_WRITE_STATUS_CALLBACK` type, and needed to typecast it to what the API expect, or use the `GetProcAddress` technique, which is needed to run the same code on XP anyway).

Am I missing something or is this really an issue with the API? And how about `EDI` and `ESI`? They are also NOT restored properly, even on Windows 7. In my case they were not used, so it's fine, but I can't believe none of the callers of these functions would need these registers to be properly restored... Right?

I think I'll file a bug to Microsoft for this... Unless someone can come up with a better explanation...

Comment: Pretty much all callback functions are __stdcall, so it seems likely that this one is too and that it is the documentation and SDK header files are wrong.  By all means file a bug, if you are able to do so.  Good catch!

Comment: I filed an issue on Connect:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/881010/rm-write-status-callback-should-specify-stdcall-or-winapi

Comment: @MAD -- put together an answer for this and I'll give you an upvote :)